# How can i select specific child nodes with xpath?

Tags: regex, xpath, katalon-studio

I'm trying to automate element finding in a table row with Katalon + XPath. I have an html table and i'd like to find the correct row which satisfies my criteria.

My first attempt was:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,\'MessageList_DXDataRow\')]/td[2] [text()='SomeSearchValue'] and td[3][contains(text(), 'SomeString')]
```

But adding simply "and" will make it return with boolean: false.

So i modified it to this:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'MessageList_DXDataRow')]/*[self::td[2][text()='SomeSearchValue'] and self::td[3][contains(text(), 'SomeString')]]
```

But it doesn't find anything.

As you can see i'd like to search for a fix value in td[2] and for a substring in td[3].

Edit:

The related html:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id="MessageList_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow table-row share row-navigable" style="font-weight: bold;">
        <td class="dxgv">FirstColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgv">SecondColumn</td>
        <td class="message-content dxgv">ThirdColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgv">FourthColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn dxgv dx-ac">FifthColumn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="MessageList_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow table-row share row-navigable" style="font-weight: bold;">
        <td class="dxgv">FirstColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgv">SecondColumn</td>
        <td class="message-content dxgv">ThirdColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgv">FourthColumn</td>
        <td class="dxgvCommandColumn dxgv dx-ac">FifthColumn</td>
    </tr>
```

How could i make it work?

Comment: Please share the HTML. At least the part around the element(s) you are trying to get.

Comment: I added a part of it with placeholders but i already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The solution that i was looking for is something like this:

```
(//*[starts-with(@id,'MessageList_DXDataRow')]/td[2][text()='SecondColumn']/following-sibling::td[1][contains(text(), 'Third')])[1]'
```

Comment: Nice. But you don't select a row with this but a td element.

Comment: In my case it didn't matter if i choose the row or it's td elements because everything navigates me to the same page when i click on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear if you wanted OR or AND condition.

This will select the row where td[2] condition or td[3] condition is satisfied :

```
//tr[starts-with(@id,'MessageList_DXDataRow')][./td[2][.="SecondColumn"] or ./td[3][contains(.,"Third")]]
```

This will select the rows where both td[2] and td[3] conditions are satisfied :

```
//tr[starts-with(@id,'MessageList_DXDataRow')][./td[2][.="SecondColumn"] and ./td[3][contains(.,"Third")]]
```

Comment: I wanted AND condition. The OR condition was a typo.